# how to I pack external tools in the package during maven build

Tags: maven

I have an existing mvn project which build into a zip file at the end.

now I need to add an external tool to it, the tool is already a single executable so I just need to include it in the final package.

what is the right way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to follow:

- Upload your artifact/tool to a maven repository, e.g. on your local maven repository server (Archiva/Artifactory/Nexus etc.)
- Use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)  to download your artifact/tool to your project target directory where you assemble your zip file
- Use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to assemble your zip file

Comment: can i just keep the executable in the local directory and refer to it in the mvn build?

Comment: This is not portable for users outside your local domain/setup and thus frowned upon for good reasons. There are ways to achieve this but it is really not a good idea in most cases.

Comment: so I can also checkin this executable into our svn. will that be ok?

Comment: Sure you may use this approach, include it in your src tree and reference it in your assembly descriptor. There are cases where this is quite ok (Your executable generally won't change) or where it is not desirable as it is part of your project. The choice is yours.

Comment: I guess my question is, how do I do it?  can you be more specific about "reference it in your assembly descriptor"

Comment: You really need to study the Maven Assembly Plugin documentation for this or give a concrete example.